# Как неравномерно распределить случайные числа

Tags: javascript

Функция заполняет массив 0 или 1.

```
  setRandomCells(array) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.maxRow; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < this.maxCol; j++ ) {
        array[i][j].active = Math.floor(Math.random()*(0 + 2)) + 0;
      }  
    }
  }
```

Как сделать преобладание 0 или 1

Comment: забить нужным числом 0 и 1 и перемешать.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать вот так вот:

```js
const random = (min, max) => {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

const randomGenerator = (arr) => () => arr[random(0, arr.length - 1)];
const randomOne = randomGenerator([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]);
const randomTwo = randomGenerator([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);

const resultOne = {0: 0, 1: 0}
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  resultOne[randomOne()] += 1;
}

const resultTwo = {0: 0, 1: 0}
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  resultTwo[randomTwo()] += 1;
}

console.log(resultOne, resultTwo);
```

Суть в том, что у нас есть массив уже с некоторым распределением 1 и 0 ( так можем контролировать чего будет больше 1 или 0 ) и потом мы просто выбираем случайное значение из этого массива